# how to update(F5) properly after a post. to display a get

Tags: javascript, reactjs, post, axios, get

I would like to explain my problem of the day.

currently, I post a message in my database, then in the same component I perform a get to display the data sent just before.

my problem and the next one I have to update the page manually to display my get,
I would like to find a solution to directly display the result without having to press F5

How can I fix this issue?thx all

make room for the code :)

post

```
postBack(e,) {   
e.preventDefault();
const payload = {
  phone: this.state.phone,
  total: this.state.total ,
}
axios.post('******', payload)
.then(res => {
  if (res.error) {
    alert(res.error); 
  } 
}).catch(e => {
  console.error(e); 

}).finally(() => this.setState({
  redirect: true
}));
}
```

get

```
getRandom = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get(
        '*****'
    )
    this.setState({ data: res.data })
}
componentDidMount() {
    this.getRandom()
}
```

render

```
render() {

    let datas = this.state.data.map(chat => {
        return (
  
    <form onSubmit={(e) => this.handleSubmit(e, chat,)}> 
      <label>
        <input  type="text" name="name" onChange={this.handleChange} />
      </label>
      <button type="submit">Envoyer</button>
      </form>
            <div key={chat.id}>
                  <div key={chat.id}>
                 <p> your name is {chat.name} </p>                   
           </div>
            </div>
        )
    })
    return (
        <div>
            {datas}
        </div>
    )
}
}
```

Comment: You can use ```window.location.reload()``` to reload the page from JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

You can update `data` state after POST request is success.
The code seems incomplete but it would be something like this

```js
postBack(e,) {   
e.preventDefault();
const payload = {
  phone: this.state.phone,
  total: this.state.total ,
}
axios.post('******', payload)
.then(res => {
  if (res.error) {
    alert(res.error); 
  } else { // here should be place to update state
    this.setState({ data: payload })
  }
}).catch(e => {
  console.error(e); 

}).finally(() => this.setState({
  redirect: true
}));
}
```